# Python: compare keys of 2 dictionaries and update the value of one

Tags: python, replace, compare

I have 2 dictionaries with the same keys:

```
d={123:'bla', 456: blabla}
e={123:'bla', 456:''}
```

Dictionary e has some empty values and if this is the case and the IDs are the same I'd like to replace the empty value with the value from d.

I am looking for something like this:

```
if d.keys()==e.keys():
    e.values==d.values()
print e
```

However, I couldn't find anything in the Python documentation that compares single keys and updates the values.

Can someone help or point me at something?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use defaultdict from collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a straight update if you don't mind overwriting differing values with

```
e.update(d)
```

or if you want to make sure you only overwrite the ones containing empty values then you will need to iterate over your dictionary to find them, and update selectively

```
# Python 2.x
for key, value in e.iteritems():
    if value == '':
        e[key] = d.get(key)

# Python 3.x
for key, value in e.items():
    if value == '':
        e[key] = d.get(key)
```

Comment: Thanks. Since my file is very, very large I'd probably prefer the second option (I guess it takes up less memory!?). However, I do get the error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'.

Comment: Ah, that `AttributeError` is because in Python3.x it was changed to just `.items()` instead. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a dict comprehension:

```
f = {k:(e[k] or d[k]) for k in e.keys()}
```

`or` evaluates to the second item if the first is empty. Of course you have to make sure both use the same keys.